# String toByte and reverse, not bijective if bytes are modified

Tags: java, arrays

Following Code changes every byte of a string and creates a new string.

```
public static String convert(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    byte[] convert = new byte[bytes.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        convert[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
    }

    return new String(convert);
}
```

**Question: Why is convert() not bijective?**

```
convert(convert("Test String")).equals("Test String") === false
```

Comment: A `String` is not just an arbitrary series of bytes.  If you want to code an arbitrary series of bytes as text, use Base64 or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use the constructor String(byte[]), it doesn't necesarily takes one letter per byte, it takes the default charset; if it is, say, UTF-8, then the constructor will try to decode some chars from two or three bytes rather than just one.

As you are using bit-complement to transform byte by byte, the result could be different when you apply the default charset.

If you are using **only** ASCII chars, you could try this version of your function:

```
// ONLY if you use ASCII as Charset
public static String convert(String s) {
    Charset ASCII = Charset.forName("ASCII");
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(ASCII);
    byte[] convert = new byte[bytes.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        convert[i] = (byte) (~bytes[i] & 0x7F);
    }

    return new String(convert, ASCII);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because information is lost when you converted the manipulated byte to String and vice versa
In this line below
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        convert[i] = (byte) ~bytes[i];
    }

```
return new String(convert);
```

If you go inside the implementation of String to byte conversion and viceversa you will find that CharSet and encoding are involved.
Read about them and you will get detailed explanation of this behavior.